# WordPress: Override filter variable not working

Tags: php, wordpress, function, filter

I'm currently trying to override a filter in a plugin. This filter has 1 variable which defines a root path to a folder where some templates are located.

This root path is normally in the assets folder of the plugin (Awesome Support). Because I want to override the templates I need to change the root path of the templates folder to my own folder so that my own templates are used and not the original ones.

---

After a lot of searching I've found the right filter in the documentation: [Filter](https://developer.getawesomesupport.com/documentation/hooks-and-filters/wpas_email_template_root_path/)

The filter gets applied in this file on line 722: [File](https://github.com/Awesome-Support/Awesome-Support/blob/develop/includes/admin/functions-tools.php)

So I've added this filter to my themes `function.php` file:

```
add_filter( 'wpas_email_template_root_path', 'set_wpas_email_template_root_path', 30, 1 );
function set_wpas_email_template_root_path( $template_root_path ) {

    error_log( 'email-functions.php' );

    return get_home_path() . 'wp-content/themes/' . get_option( 'stylesheet' ) . '/awesome-support/emails/';
}
```

To test it I've added some error logging in my function and at the place where I need to override the root path:

```
error_log( 'Before' );
// Allow other add-ons to set this path
apply_filters( 'wpas_email_template_root_path', $template_root_path );
error_log( 'functions-tools.php' . $template_root_path );
```

This is the debugging result:

```
[08-Jan-2019 08:56:19 UTC] Before
[08-Jan-2019 08:56:19 UTC] email-functions.php
[08-Jan-2019 08:56:19 UTC] functions-tools.php/var/www/vhosts/localhost/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/awesome-support/assets/admin/email-templates/blue-block/
```

As you can see there is still the plugins template path set. I don't know what I'm doing wrong here..

Comment: have you tried prioritizing the run time of the hook? - e.g. `add_filter( 'wpas_email_template_map_to_files', 'wpas_override_email_template_map', 9);`

Comment: Yes, but not working..

Comment: To be clear, if you want to override the variable values (not a function), your filter needs to run last, so the 'priority' must be higher (later) than any others.  You could also temporarily add some debugs around the 'apply_filter' statement to make sure code is getting there, and also inside your wpas_override_email_template_map to be sure it is executing

Comment: @anmari I've tried every prio but the filter is always added after the value is set so this has no impact. I don't know what I should try.

Comment: Yes the values will have been set.  What you are trying to do is overwrite them?  Is your filter firing ?  ACTUALLY Looking at lines 722 and your code, it seems to me that all you are actually trying to do is change the template path.  All your template  names are the same, but you've added code to fetch the stylesheet?

Comment: What? I just want to set my own template path where exact the same templates are located but which my changes.

Comment: I've changed my question to just one topic to make it more clear. Check it out.

Comment: I'd get really pedantic with the debug then.  I'd set $path = get_home_path() . 'wp-content/themes/' . get_option( 'stylesheet' ) . '/awesome-support/emails/'; and dump it in the error log too.  JUST to be sure

Comment: Did this. The path is right. I'v wrote to the plugin developer and he said that this is a bug after testing it.

Comment: In your modified version of his code you'd lost the $template_root_path = apply-filters

Comment: Yes, thats the reason. But this is the original file. I've did not changes there. Just added the debugging things. This is a "bug" which will be fixed in the new beta release.

Answer (score 0):

Plugin author said that this is a bug. This is the commit of the fix:

https://github.com/Awesome-Support/Awesome-Support/commit/4312c02a3e35bb369e943d807377610670e71f41